# compiling tesseract and open_cv through NDK android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

i have a c++ program that is for OCR (optical character recognition using open_cv, tesseract, leptonica) and it is running good on Linux Ubuntu using scons.
Now i want to use this code in my android project using NDK or anything but i don't know how to link all the libraries.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the NDK tutorials?

Basically, you'll need to build these both librairies, and you'll load them (the .so files) with Java call, and call functions on these librairies using JNI. I think they already provide JNI calls, so you have "just" to build them.

Or if you can be more specific about what are your problems ?